# Specifying delivery addresses on channel closes - includes force closes?

Tags: address, lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, hacking

In https://github.com/lnbook/lnbook/blob/develop/07_payment_channels.asciidoc

We see this block of text:

> Typically the addresses used in this cooperative close transaction are
> generated freshly for each channel being closed. However, it’s also
> possible for both sides to lock in a "delivery" address to be used to
> send their cooperatively settled funds to. Within the TLV namespace of
> both the open_channel and accept_channel messages, both sides are free
> to specify an "upfront shutdown script". Commonly, this address is
> derived from keys that reside in cold storage. This practice serves to
> increase the security of channels: if a channel partner is somehow
> hacked, then the hacker isn’t able to cooperatively close the channel
> using an address they control. Instead, the uncompromised honest
> channel partner will refuse to cooperate on a channel closure if the
> specified upfront shutdown address isn’t used. This feature
> effectively creates a "closed loop", restricting the flow of funds out
> of a given channel.

It seems like delivery addresses are only for cooperative closes based on this text. Can you still specify a delivery addresses for any close type, including force close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"it's just for co-op close, the force close "address" is already locked in: the P2WSH script itself" Roasbeef

Another note that dawned on me. For situations where you want to do a force close, your channel partner wouldn't be able to specify any new data.. So ofc you would need to know where the remote balance is going, and this is the same for the local balance.